# How to make a "nearby places" request or custom filter with API Platform in a geolocation application?

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm developing a project and registered in my `property` entity places with their latitudes and longitudes. What I'd like to do is to perform a request to retrieve nearby places, let's say in a radius of 5 or 10 miles around the current user position. Any idea how to achieve that? Thanks in advance.
P.S. I came across [this blogpost](https://intelligentbee.com/2017/09/14/get-nearby-locations-mysql-database/) but I couldn't implement it as a custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom filter to your entity.

You can look into [the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-doctrine-orm-filters) for detailed infos